# Cycles Render vs Baked Texture... Not Even Close

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, lighting

i don't get this.

so here's my object, in 'preview render' mode.  you can see it is almost totally washed out with light.  YET, when i bake the texture, i always get a muddy middle-toned colour all over the surface.

[image]

why does the bake texture not resemble the render preview?  (i was told they will 'never be the same' but this is... QUITE different, and i can't seem to lighten up the bake.)

i have one sun light in the scene, straight overhead.
i set the world background colour to white.
i then added a sphere around the objects and set it to emissive, to try to get an ambient light all around.

is it possible the emissive sphere is casting a shadow on the object?  is there a toggle that makes it not cast shadows in the render?  or something?

also, i was reading that cycles render doesn't recognize hemisphere lamps, and just treats them as sun lamps.  is that still even the case??

in my image, i have posted my material (it is super basic), render settings, world settings, sun lamp settings...  what am i doing wrong?  am i missing something?

Comment: Please share your blend file so that I can take a look at it? You can do this by uploading the blend file on this site - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and copy + pasting the generated url here.